# What is a Vector4 in Unity engine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have found [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector4.html) doc for `Vector4` in Unity engine. What do you need a Vector4 for? Also, apart from the `x, y, and z` axes, what is the `w axis` for?

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/59970/what-is-vector3-vector4-etc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this

[In OpenGL vertex shaders, what is w, and why do I divide by it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422750/in-opengl-vertex-shaders-what-is-w-and-why-do-i-divide-by-it)

Thread which explains why the w - component is used in an opengl
vertex shader, in unity it should pretty much have the same meaning.